# Kotlin equivalent of Swift Expectations/Promises

Tags: swift, unit-testing, kotlin, promise, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to write some UnitTests for my native mobile applications, but have ran into a roadblock in my Android Tests. Specifically, I am struggling to find an example of Kotlin's version of Swift's Expectations/Promises..

I've found examples of Kotlin Promises, but they seem to be way more complicated than needed...

For example, here is a test for the login API function in my iOS project:

```
func testLogin() {

    /// Prepare for login
    if CURRENT_USER != nil {
        logout()
    }

    /// Login
    let promise = expectation(description: "User is logged in.")

    // 1. Given
    var isSuccess: Bool = false

    // 2. When
    User.login(username: maleUsername, password: malePassword, success: {
        isSuccess = true
        promise.fulfill()
    }) { (_, agreeToTerms) in
        XCTFail()
    }
    wait(for: [promise], timeout: maxTimeOut)

    // 3. Then
    XCTAssertNotNil(CURRENT_USER)
    XCTAssertTrue(isSuccess)

    /// Logout
    logout()
}
```

This is pretty simple to me. I have an asynchronous method `login` that has two possible completion blocks: `success` and `failure`; and I need to wait for one of them to complete before evaluating. To do this, I create a **promise** before the call, then I **fulfill** the promise in the two completion blocks, and I **wait** for the promise to fulfill before running my assertions.

Now in Kotlin, I have a similar test:

```
private val loginFragment = LoginFragment()

@Test
fun loginTest() {

    val username = ""
    val password = ""

    // TODO: Create Promise

    loginFragment.loginViewModel
            .login(username, password)
            .observe(loginFragment, Observer {
                loginFragment.activity?.onResult(it?.result,

                        onSuccess = {
                            // TODO: Fill Promise
                        },
                        onValidationError = {
                            // TODO: Fail Test
                        })
            })

    // TODO: Assertions

}
```

But I can't find an equivalent of swift's promises..

Does one exist in Kotlin? If not, how would I implement a version of my Swift's `testLogin` method in Kotlin?

Comment: This might help: https://medium.com/@tonyowen/android-kotlin-coroutines-unit-test-16e984ba35b4

Comment: The most straightforward analog of a promise on Kotlin-Android is the plain old `CompletableFuture`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Kotlin coroutines, for example:

```
@Test
fun loginTest() {
    val result = runBlocking {
        val loginResult = login() 
        loginResult
    }
    if (result == "Success") {
        // do your work when Success
    } else {
        // do your work when Error
    }
}
suspend fun login(): String = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
    val username = ""
    val password = ""
    loginFragment.loginViewModel
    .login(username, password)
    .observe(loginFragment, Observer {
        loginFragment.activity?.onResult(it?.result,

                    onSuccess = {
                        continuation.resume("Success")
                    },
                    onValidationError = {
                        continuation.resume("Error") // take a look for other methods, e.g. resumeWithException(exception)

                    })
    })   
}
```

To use coroutines you need to add next lines to app's build.gradle file dependencies:

> ```
> final KOTLIN_COROUTINES_VERSION = '1.0.1'
> implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$KOTLIN_COROUTINES_VERSION"
> ```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for the information. So if I were to use this, I would essentially have to write a suspend function and a function that runs the suspend function for every test?

Comment: Yes, the code is more clear and readable that way. You can try avoid of creating of  `login()` method by moving `suspendCoroutine {}` block inside `runBlocking {}`, but there will be some mess in the code.

Comment: Talk about the lesser of two evils... haha.

Comment: I prefer to create a new method with `suspendCoroutine {}` block :)

Comment: I'll be doing separate methods. Kotlin is kinda lame in the sense that you have to choose between (A) concise, but complicated, ultra-nested, messy code or (B) expansive, but simple, readable, clean code. Swift seems to be both clean and concise

Comment: You'e welcome. Btw you can accept my answer if it works for you.

Comment: I'm actually having an issue with the `runBlocking` part. It says it was introduced in Kotlin 1.3, but anything I look up about Kotlin 1.3 says a stable version for JetBrains?? Do you have any tips on that? Thanks.

Comment: I understand that is a different issue, so I will mark it as complete once I figure this Kotlin issue out and can confirm your solution suites my needs.

Comment: try to update Kotlin's plugin in Android Studio and change version of Kotlin in build.gradle file of your app

Comment: I tried that but then got the error: `"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.3.0" is unresolved`. I posted a new issue about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53306434/update-android-studio-project-to-kotlin-1-3

Comment: I answered the question. Did it help?

Comment: Sure did! Thanks

Comment: great, glad to help

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](https://github.com/Shopify/promise-kotlin) Kotlin Promise lib closer to Swift Promises.
Using this library your test would like.

```
@Test
fun loginTest() {
    val username = ""
    val password = ""

    Promise<Boolean, Exception> { promise ->
        loginFragment.loginViewModel
            .login(username, password)
            .observe(loginFragment, Observer {
                loginFragment.activity?.onResult(it?.result,

                    onSuccess = {
                        promise.resolve(true)
                    },
                    onValidationError = {
                        promise.reject(Exception("Login error"))
                    })
            })
    }.whenComplete {
        when (it) {
            is Promise.Result.Success -> {
                assert(it.value)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote in 20 minutes an implementation that looks like swift's `expectation`, but he is not sophisticated, use only for simple cases it does the work well.

```kotlin
typealias XCTestExceptionHandler = (KTTestException?) -> Unit

fun TestCase.expectation(description: String): KTTestExpectation {
    return KTTestExpectation(description)
}

fun TestCase.waitFor(expectation: KTTestExpectation, timeout: Long, handler: XCTestExceptionHandler) {
    expectation.handler = handler

    Thread.sleep(timeout)
    expectation.timedOut()
}

class KTTestExpectation(private val description: String) {
    private var isFulfilled = false
    var handler: XCTestExceptionHandler? = null

    fun fulfill() {
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            invokeHandlerWith(null)
        }, 2)
    }

    fun timedOut() {
        invokeHandlerWith(KTTestException("Timed out: $description"))
    }

    private fun invokeHandlerWith(error: KTTestException?) {
        if (isFulfilled) return
        isFulfilled = true
        handler?.invoke(error)
        error?.let { Assert.fail("Timed out: $description") }
    }
}

class KTTestException(message:String): Exception(message)
```

Using:

```kotlin
    fun testExpectation() {
        var nb = 0
        val expectation = expectation("Test")

        MyAsyncFunc {
            nb = 5
            expectation.fulfill()
        }

        waitFor(expectation, 1000) { error ->
            assertEquals(5, nb)
        }
    }
```

If anyone has the courage to convert the original code to Kotlin Here are the links:
https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-xctest/blob/main/Sources/XCTest/Public/Asynchronous/XCTWaiter.swift

https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-xctest/blob/main/Sources/XCTest/Public/Asynchronous/XCTestExpectation.swift

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in the same situation. I needed an equivalent of Swift's expectations and I couldn't work around it using Kotlin Coroutines, so I decided to make a small library to implement it. Maybe it will be useful for someone else.

https://github.com/danielepantaleone/KTTestExpectation