# Update Android Studio Project to Kotlin 1.3

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am attempting to Use Kotlin Coroutine's `runBlocking` function, but I receive the error that this method was introduced in Kotlin 1.3.

So, I tried updating my Android Studio project to use Kotlin `1.3.0`

But, when I do that, I get the error: `"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.3.0" is unresolved`...

What is the recommended way to update my Android Studio project to use Kotlin 1.3? Or is there another method similar to `runBlocking` that is compatible with Kotlin `1.2.51`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it has different version. Try to use:

> implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.0'