# Error : Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.3.10. in Android Studio 3.3 RC 1

Tags: android, kotlin

When update android studio to **3.3 RC 1** and build the project *(run perfectly in previous version of android studio)* then its show me following error:

```
ERROR: The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.0 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
root project 'GPS_Speedometer_material' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71
```

according to this error I have update the kotlin version `1.2.17 to 1.3.0`

but it show me following error:

```
Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.3.0.
```

also try the latest kotlin version but same error:

`Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.3.10.`

Here is my **build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-rc01'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
        classpath "com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Related answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52585894/6891563

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update Android Studio Project to Kotlin 1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53306434/update-android-studio-project-to-kotlin-1-3)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to change `kotlin-stdlib-jre8` => `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8`

[Kotlin standard library artifacts and split packages](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#kotlin-standard-library-artifacts-and-split-packages)

The last version of `jre8`is 1.2.71 according to [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre8).

Comment: God bless your existence.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps : 
1.Open Your project. 
2.Go to the Left side of the Gradle button. 
3. [image]
4.Click button above image show. 
5. if this type of view you are not in offline mode. 
6. Go to Build and rebucild the project.

All above point is work for me.